# How can I identify the closest point for a list of different points and store the ID in a list

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply

I have two dataframes which have xy coordinates for different IDs at different timepoints. What I would like to do is identify which point in the previous year is closest to the point in current year and store that data in a list. So for this example data:

```
oldnames <- c('A', 'B', 'C')
oldx <- c(0,5,10)
oldy <- c(0,5,10)
olddf <- data.frame(oldnames, oldx, oldy)

newnames <- c('D','E','F')
newx <- c(1, 6, 11)
newy <- c(1, 6, 11)
newdf <- data.frame(newnames, newx, newy)
```

I would like to produce a list that looks like this:

```
names  closest
D      A
E      B
F      C
```

I've been trying to do this using apply (as below), but at the moment it gives me an error message: 
(Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator)

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
closestdf <- data.frame()
apply(newdf, 1, function(row) {
    name <- row["names"]
    xID <- row["x"]  
    yID <- row["y"]
    closest <- olddf %>%
               mutate(length = sqrt((xID - oldx)^2 + (yID - oldy)^2)) %>%
               mutate(rank = min_rank(length)) %>%
               filter(rank == '1')%>%
               mutate(total =  '1')
               closestdf <- rbind(closest, closestdf)
})
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for apply calls, we can `purrr` inside the `mutate` instead:

```
library(tidyverse)
newdf %>% 
  mutate(closest = 
           map2_chr(newx, newy, 
                    ~as.character(olddf$oldnames)[which.min((.x - olddf$oldx) ^ 2 + (.y - olddf$oldy) ^ 2)]
           )
  )
```

Gives:

> ```
>   newnames newx newy closest
> 1        D    1    1       A
> 2        E    6    6       B
> 3        F   11  101       C
> ```

There is no reason to perform the square root operation if we don't need the actual distance.

Or more clear and verbose with intermediate steps:

```
newdf %>% 
  mutate(dists = map2(newx, newy, ~(.x - olddf$oldx) ^ 2 + (.y - olddf$oldy) ^ 2),
         ids = map_dbl(dists, which.min),
         closest = olddf$oldnames[ids])
```

Gives:

> ```
>   newnames newx newy             dists ids closest
> 1        D    1    1        2, 32, 162   1       A
> 2        E    6    6         72, 2, 32   2       B
> 3        F   11  101 10322, 9252, 8282   3       C
> ```

Comment: Great thanks for that! For the top solution, should it be     [which.min((.x - olddf$oldx ^ 2) + (.y - olddf$oldy) ^ 2)]  instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry I was too quick.